# How to remove redundant (similar items) from a 2 dimensional array in perl

Tags: arrays, list, perl, awk

I am rather new to perl, but so far I have found it a very strong language.
Every month I pull an extract from a license register for a product that I am managing, and the data is in CSV format.
I have managed to complete the code to get a sorted list, and also sorted as per my requirements. The list is some 1200 rows.

The format of the list looks like this (I have kept only the vital parts):

```
Customer;CustomerID;ProductLine;Platform;Version
operatorx;1234;XX;Linux;15
operatorx;1234;YY;x86;7
operatorx;1234;ZZ;Sparc;7
operatory;2345;YY;x86;8
operatory;2345;YY;Sparc;7.1
operatory;2345;ZZ;x86;7.2
```

The output wanted is like this for the above:

```
Customer;CustomerID;ProductLine;Platform;Version
operatorx;1234;XX;Linux;15
operatory;2345;YY;x86;8
operatory;2345;ZZ;x86;7.2
```

My list in the code does not contain any ';', the values are stored in a array like this:

```
@sortedlist = ([Customer,customerID,ProductLine,Platform,Version])
```

So any customer can have many rows in my original list, but if the product is XX, then only the first occurrence in the list should be kept, and no occurrences of product YY or ZZ can be kept.
If a customer has no product XX, then the first occurrence of product YY and first occurrence of product ZZ should be kept.

The list is sorted so that the "best" entry is always the first per customerID.

I have tried a very simple code, checking that current customerID != prevCustomerID then push the row to a new list, but this makes me miss out when a customer has both products YY and ZZ...
I have also tried nesting a lot of if statements, to try to keep track of current row and previous row... but the code grew a lot, and still didn't give me the expected result :-(

I am starting to think that I approach this from the wrong angle, and I have tried to dig into hashes, but since a customer can actually have one or two entries in the final list, I think a hash is disqualified, as the key value here has to be customerID, and in a hash, there should only be one occurrence per customerID.

Does anyone have any idea on how to attack this problem?
Starting from the top, push the very first element to a new list, and then for each consecutive row, check if it exists in the new list, and what product the new list contains, and if product == XX, then scrap the rest for the same customerID, or if product in the new list == YY, scrap the rest until it finds product == ZZ for the same customerID. Then repeat the same, until it finds a new customerID?

--- updated ---
I managed to solve my issue using awk instead.

```
./myperlscript.pl input.csv | awk -F ';' '!array[$1,$2,$3]++'| awk -F ';' '{ {if ($2 != prev) {print $0; prev = $2; prevprod = $3}} {if ($2 = prev && prevprod != "XX") { prev =$2}}} > output.csv
```

But if anyone whould know how to achieve the same with standard perl, it would be very nice.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post the code you've got so far. And also explain why you're artificially restricting the solution space to not include modules. You can, however, have hashes of arrays, and arrays of hashes. 
 Or hashes of hashes. Or compound hash-keys.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and follow the guidelines to include sufficient information to describe your problem.

Comment: To Sobrique: The reason for not wanting to use modules, is that I want to share my final code with my colleagues, we are not able to use CPAN in the setup we have... Our main env is Windows based, and we have to use Cygwin to run this, and our Cygwin setup that we have to use, does not allow adding modules :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive implementation in perl using state variables that achieves the same result.  If you actually have more than 3 variables to consier (XX,YY,ZZ here), you could generalize this into a state array and a function that updates the array and decides what to do based on the state of the array.

**filter.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $last_customer = '';
my ($seen_xx, $seen_yy, $seen_zz);

while (my $line = <>) {
    # Header
    if ($. == 1) {
        print $line;
        next;
    }

    # Data
    my ($customer_name, $customer_id, $product_line, $platform, $version) = split /;/, $line;
    die "Unable to parse line : $line"
        unless defined $customer_name;

    if ($customer_name ne $last_customer) {
        $last_customer = $customer_name;
        ($seen_xx, $seen_yy, $seen_zz) = (0,0,0); # Reset
    }

    if (not $seen_xx and $product_line eq 'XX') {
        # Print first XX
        print $line;
        ($seen_xx, $seen_yy, $seen_zz) = (1,1,1); # Ignore the others
    }

    if (not $seen_yy and $product_line eq 'YY') {
        # Print first YY if no XX
        print $line;
        $seen_yy = 1;
    }

    if (not $seen_zz and $product_line eq 'ZZ') {
        # Print first ZZ if no XX
        print $line;
        $seen_zz = 1;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
cat input | perl filter.pl
Customer;CustomerID;ProductLine;Platform;Version
operatorx;1234;XX;Linux;15
operatory;2345;YY;x86;8
operatory;2345;ZZ;x86;7.2
```